# Show div3 above div2 but beneath the background, while div2 is above the background?

Tags: css

I have no idea if this is possible, but if it is, it would make everything so much easier.

So, I have 2 divs, div1 and div2.
div1 is partly covered with div2, as shown below

[image]

However, I'd like div2 to *below* the background, as shown below

[image]

Is this possible in any way?

Comment: Can you put together a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I'm confused by the use of circles instead of rectangles

Comment: Have you considered changing up the z-index values within the CSS?

[Here's a link to the z-index attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4NzTh/ ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution you can use overflow:hidden for that

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uYvKs/)

```
.red {
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    background:red;
    border-radius:80px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
.green {
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    background:green;
    border-radius:80px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    left:60%
}
```